# How to store and modify angles in 3D space

Tags: c++, rotation, game-physics, glm-math

This isn't about understanding angular physics, but more how to actually implement it.

For example, I'm using a simple linear interpolation per frame (with dT)
I'm having trouble with the angular units, I want to be able to rotate around arbitrary axes.

(with glm)
Using a `vec3` for torque, inertia and angular velocity works excellent for a single axis.
Any more and you get gimbal lock. (i.e. You can rotate around a local x, y or z but superimposing prevents proper results)

Using quaternions I can't get it to function nicely with time, inertia or for an extended period.

Is there any tried-and-true method for representing these features?

Comment: Exactly how do you have angular velocity around multiple axis? Even if your rotation isn't aligned with your world axis, it's still going to rotate around a single axis (certainly since you're not mentioning precession)

Comment: I don't mean separate, just accumulative.  e.g rotating around (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0) results in a rotation around (0.5, 0.5, 0)

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Rotations are defined by an axis and an angle.

Comment: Angular velocities accumulate no?
I left out the angles and simply stated the axes so what's the problem?

Comment: No, they don't. Angles accumulate only when the axis align.

Comment: Each approach has its own (dis)advantages and there is no tried-and-true method. In your case, you could perhaps use the exponential map. Check the following paper for an overview of the exponential map and its differences w.r.t. quaternions, matrices, etc. "Grassia, F. Sebastian. "Practical parameterization of rotations using the exponential map." Journal of graphics tools 3.3 (1998): 29-48."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution is to use the [matrix representation of rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Two rotations in sequence can be expressed by multiplying their respective matrices. And because matrix multiplication is not symmetric, the order of the 2 rotations matters - as it should.

Comment: So your suggestion is for each accumulated torque, add a rotation to a stack/array/collection and iterate each update?

Comment: No, I didn't. Torque is not rotation. You can't accumulate those. I think you're confusing too many different concepts. For instance, rotation and angular velocity. And when you mention torque, you enter the physics domain where _moments of inertia_ becomes relevant - something that depends on the axis along which you're rotating.

Comment: I know that, I think my misunderstanding is that my Undergraduate courses only covered angular mechanics in 2d (so only 1 possible axis at a time.)

Is there anything you could suggest to help me apply it to 3d?

Comment: Nothing simple I'm afraid. Once your physical model implements non-aligned torques, you'll have a model that's complex enough to represent a precessing gyroscope. And those are of course even more magical than magnets ;)

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, I'm going to accept this answer because while I may not have a specific answer, you've certainly helped me find the next question :)